# I want to create a div that can dragged inside the parent div and dropped?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

The dragable object after dropping inside the div shows a text message that appears in modal or in p below the div that says "object is dropped"

Comment: Please include your code attempt in your question. We are not a coding service.

Comment: [Please visit here for more on how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could user [Jquery-UI Droppable](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/) component.

Sample code:

```
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me to my target</p>
</div>

<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>Drop here</p>
</div>
```

and:

```
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( this )
      .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
      .find( "p" )
        .html( "Dropped!" );
  }
});
```

Edit:
You need to add the jQuery and jQuery-UI libraries:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Please note that this example was taken from the jQuery UI web site.

Edit:
See [this fiddle example.](https://jsfiddle.net/5zqxp1pq/)

Basically you need to add your logic in the drop event. This is just a simple example that does really nothing but change the background color of the drop zone.

Comment: thank you for your reply but could you please make a fiddle or provide me any demo of this because I am unable to use this code on my page :(

Comment: You have to include jquery and jquery-ui libraries, see the edit in the example and please mark as a solution if it was helpful for you :)

Comment: I am sorry but its still not working could you please make a snippet, jsfiddle or codepen I mean a working example will be a great help thank you.

Comment: <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="js/custom.js"></script>

<script>
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( this )
      .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
      .find( "p" )
        .html( "Dropped!" );
  }
});
</script>

added this in my footer

Comment: Please check the edit, I included a full fiddle example.

Comment: Thank you for your help I had market it completed but there is one last thing if you could also do that, I just want this box to be stopped being dragged after placing it in the main box or else the text should change from dropped to drop here if the draggable box is moved out because right now its making less sense if we drag the box out again btw thanks once again.

Comment: You really need to try it on your own. Here's an updated sample with disabled draggable after dropping:   https://jsfiddle.net/5zqxp1pq/1/